# mysql BETWEEN equivalent in MongoDB

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

In PHP & MongoDB, i am trying to read all instances of events for a specific calendar and a specific period. Each event has start and end date. They are of MongoDate type in mongodb.

I use below condition to get the events from mongo.

```
$condition = array(
 'start_time'    => array('$gte'    =>  new MongoDate($start_day)), 
 'end_time'      => array('$lte'    => new MongoDate($end_day))
);
```

Here is my problem, i am missing the events whose start date is to my date range.

For example 
event starts on **01-july-2014**
event ends on **10-july-2014**

my mongo query  - give me events from 5-july to 12-july

```
$condition = array(
  'start_time'    =>    array('$gte'    => '5-july-2014'), 
  'end_time'      =>    array('$lte'    => '12-july-2014')
);
```

**When i run above mentioned event is not returned.**

Any suggestions are welcome?

In mysql BETWEEN helps me to get the required results.

Comment: Which event is not returned? Also show the "working" mysql query.

Comment: the event i mentioned which starts on 01-july-2014. i use 3 to 4 or conditions with start end dates with between in mysql.

Comment: i should remove mysql equivalent and just look for mongo specific solution.

Comment: "I use 3 to 4 or conditions" - then why do you expect this simple query to behave like the far more complicated one?

Comment: I encountered a similar problem recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403970/mongodb-mapreduce-necessary-range-query-on-dates-in-a-booking-application/24447161#24447161

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query selects any events which are *completely contained* in the given date range, but when I understood you correctly you want events which *partly or completely overlap* the date-range.

A date-range overlaps another date-range when the start of A is before the end of B and the end of A is after the start of B. So try

```
'event_start'    => array('$lte'    =>  new MongoDate($search_end)), 
'event_end'      => array('$gte'    => new MongoDate($search_start))
```

Another pitfall I should mention is that a MongoDate doesn't represent a single day, but an exact point in time. When you omit the time, you get midnight at that date. So `'$lte'    => '12-july-2014'` gives you `2014-04-12 0:00:00.000` which will not select anything *on* july 12th. When you want to include that day, either manually set a time like `12-july-2014 23:59:59` or just use the next day.

Comment: it doesn't help if my event end date is 20-july-2014

Comment: @codepiper It should. 20-july-2014 is greater-than-or-equal 5-july-2014. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @checked again to this logic, it worked fine. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No direct equivalent of "between", but with data like this:

```js
{
    "start_time" : ISODate("2014-07-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "end_time" : ISODate("2014-07-10T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "start_time" : ISODate("2014-07-05T00:00:00Z"),
    "end_time" : ISODate("2014-07-12T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "start_time" : ISODate("2014-07-07T00:00:00Z"),
    "end_time" : ISODate("2014-07-14T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "start_time" : ISODate("2014-07-13T00:00:00Z"),
    "end_time" : ISODate("2014-07-14T00:00:00Z")
}
```

This works:

```js
db.collection.find(
    {
        "$or": [
            { "start_time": { 
                "$gte": new Date("2014-07-05"),
                "$lte": new Date("2014-07-12")
              }
            },
            { "end_time":   { 
                "$gte": new Date("2014-07-05"),
                "$lte": new Date("2014-07-12")
              } 
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

And produces:

```js
{
    "start_time" : ISODate("2014-07-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "end_time" : ISODate("2014-07-10T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "start_time" : ISODate("2014-07-05T00:00:00Z"),
    "end_time" : ISODate("2014-07-12T00:00:00Z")
}
{
    "start_time" : ISODate("2014-07-07T00:00:00Z"),
    "end_time" : ISODate("2014-07-14T00:00:00Z")
}
```

Which is just the items that would have dates within the range "between" start and end.